# Sending Codacy code coverage with Fastlane

Tags: ios, bash, fastlane, codacy

I'm trying to send the code coverage report that is created by Slather to Codacy using Fastlane. This is the lane:

```
  desc "Do A Slather and send to Codacy"
  lane :code_coverage do |options|
    slather(output_directory: "SlatherReports", scheme: "MyApp", configuration: "Debug", workspace: "MyApp.xcworkspace", proj: "MyApp.xcodeproj", cobertura_xml: true, use_bundle_exec: true)
    ENV["CODACY_PROJECT_TOKEN"] = options[:codacy_token]
    sh "bash <(curl -Ls https://coverage.codacy.com/get.sh -r SlatherReports/cobertura.xml)"
  end
```

The Slather worked but the bash script didn't. It returned this error:

> [06:40:19]: Exit status of command 'bash <(curl -Ls
>   https://coverage.codacy.com/get.sh -r SlatherReports/cobertura.xml)'
>   was 2 instead of 0. sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token
>   `(' sh: -c: line 0: `bash <(curl -Ls
>   https://coverage.codacy.com/get.sh -r SlatherReports/cobertura.xml)'

So, how do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the answer myself. And it's a very simple one (why didn't I think of this earlier?). I just put the whole `bash <(curl -Ls https://coverage.codacy.com/get.sh -r SlatherReports/cobertura.xml)` line into a different bash script file and call it instead. LOL.